# 940922 - how to reach my ssh server?

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty

my company blocks almost all connections. only i can browse web by my web browser via a proxy server on port 8080 which requires authentication. no limit in browsing https exists. but beyond that it seems that everything is blocked. when i'm at home, i use putty to create a tunnel via ssh to a purchased vps abroad. then i configure firefox to use the tunnel to reach banned sites like facebook and youtube. yes, they're filtered in my country! anyway, at company limitations are increased and i can connect to the internet via browser only. now i want to be able to use putty or any other software to create the tunnel and be able to overcome my country's filters and browse the sites. in proxy section of putty, i entered the proxy ip and port, username and password, but it seems that the ports (ssh port or something) are also banned to. how can firefox reach the internet? i need putty reach my server that way. is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either set up a VPN which talks on port 443 and use that.  Alternatively you might get away (glacially slowly) with a DNS tunnel.

You should check if port 443 is also routed through the proxy and if there are any company root certs - its entirely possible that your HTTPS traffic is being MITM'd - which means you can expect to have your IT department on your case when they see what you are doing.

You may be able to bring up SSH on your server on port 443 and communicate directly with it from your client - assuming that it is not filtered.

Comment: how can i get sure that the port is open and i can reach port 443 on my server? eg. telnet to port 443 of my server or what? please give me an step-by-step guide.